# Difference between space-like and time-like singularities

Tags: singularities

See the Wikipedia article on [Penrose-Hawking singularity theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems).

It says that

*A singularity in solutions of the Einstein field equations is one of two things:*

*1. a situation where matter is forced to be compressed to a point (a space-like singularity)*

*2. a situation where certain light rays come from a region with infinite curvature (a time-like singularity)*

If matter is forced to be compressed to a point, why is this called a *space-like* singularity?

If certain light rays come from a region with infinite curvature, why is this called a *time-like* singularity?

Comment: Spacelike and timelike singularities mean that spacelike (resp. Timelike) curves are incomplete and stop at that point.

Comment: When you say that a curve is geodesically incomplete, do you mean that the curve starts at infinity but ends at a finite point?

Comment: It means that, given any point on that curve, if the curve is normalized, it will only have a finite range in either the future or past direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacelike singularity is a spacelike region where curvature diverges. It is not a point, though it occurs when the radial distance in the metric approaches zero $r~\rightarrow~0$. This is a three dimensional region. The time like singularity is a one dimensional region, think of it a a point evolving in time, where curvature diverges. This has a duality with the spacelike singularity, being one dimensional and orthogonal to the spatial directions of a spacelike singularity.

Think of the Schwarzschild metric with signature $(+,~-,~-,~-)$
$$
ds^2~=~\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)dt^2~-~\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2~-~r^2(d\theta^2~+~sin^2\theta d^2\phi),
$$
and see that the metric term $\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)$ flips sign when $r~<~\frac{2GM}{c^2}$. This means the interior of the black hole has signature $(-,~+,~-,~-)$, and in a sense the radial direction serves at a time direction. The $t,~\theta,~\phi$ part of the metric defines the spatial surface.

An infalling observer does not notice anything. It is not as if the radial direction becomes something measured on a clock. However, the observer interior to the black hole will be unable to avoid the singularity. The Penrose conformal diagram illustrates the singularity at the top

[image]

You are basically doomed to reach the singularity in a finite time period because it is everywhere in your possible future. In fact if you try to rocket away then since you are not on a geodesic, and geodesics are the maximal path, you in fact seal your fate earlier.

The case for the timelike singularity occurs with charge or angular momentum. I will use the Reissnor-Nordstrom metric since it is simpler to understand than the Kerr metric. In fact it is a modification of the Schwarzschild metric
$$
ds^2~=~\left(1~-~\frac{2m}{r}~+~\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)dt^2~-~\left(1~-~\frac{2m}{r}~+~\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2~-~r^2(d\theta^2~+~sin^2\theta d^2\phi),
$$
Since the metric coefficient $\left(1~-~\frac{2m}{r}~+~\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)$ is quadratic in $r$ is vanishes at two radii. There is an inner and outer horizon determined by $r_{\pm}~=~m~\pm~\sqrt{m^2~-~Q^2}$. There is then an inner horizon where the metric flips signature again. This means the region is timelike and the region $r~=~0$ is a point in space evolving in time. This is seen in the Penrose diagram

[image]

There are subtleties, such as the inner horizon might turn out to be a mass inflation singularity. There is a pile up of null curves there. This appears similar to a Cauchy horizon that could be a sort of singularity. The region with the timelike singularity could be a mathematical fiction.